# Collect all values in a multidimensional array with a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 13,
        'children' => [
            ['id' => 14, 'parent_id' => 13],
            ['id' => 15, 'parent_id' => 13],
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can I get all [id] values from this array and store them in a flat array like this:

```
[13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$a` is your original array.

```
array_merge(array($a['id']),
            array_map(function($child) { return $child['id']; }, $a['children']));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recursive approach, it won't matter how long or how deep your array is.  `array_walk_recursive()` will visit every "leafnode" in the array; if the key to that leafnode is `id`, then push the value into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AXD2F))

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($v, $k) use(&$result) {
        if ($k === 'id') {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }
);
var_export($result);
```